# WordPress conditionals not working

Tags: conditional-tags

Hi I am building a jquery accordion which works fine on my site.

However I am now trying to introduce conditionals to only enable it on posts and pages, however it doesn't work, it seems the conditionals don't detect that it's a page.

The code is here: http://pastebin.com/9anYAKa1

```
function faq_start_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {
   return '<div id="accordion">';
}

function faq_question_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {
   return '<div class="accordionButton">' . $content . '</div>';
}

function faq_answer_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {
   return '<div class="accordionContent">' . $content . '</div>';
}

function faq_end_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {
   return '</div>';
}


if ( is_single() || is_page() ) {
add_shortcode('faqstart', 'faq_start_shortcode');
add_shortcode('question', 'faq_question_shortcode');
add_shortcode('answer', 'faq_answer_shortcode');
add_shortcode('faqend', 'faq_end_shortcode');
}
```

Comment: Can you please post the code *in your question*, both for posterity and for those who (*ahem*) might not have access to Pastebin?

Comment: ok pasted it in question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you're wrapping your `add_action()` calls inside of the conditionals, but at the point at which those `add_action()` calls are executed, neither the query nor the query conditionals are available yet.

Solution: put the conditionals *inside the callbacks*:

```
function faq_start_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {
    if ( is_single() || is_page() ) {
        return '<div id="accordion">';
    }
}

function faq_question_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {
    if ( is_single() || is_page() ) {
        return '<div class="accordionButton">' . $content . '</div>';
    }
}

function faq_answer_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {
    if ( is_single() || is_page() ) {
        return '<div class="accordionContent">' . $content . '</div>';
    }
}

function faq_end_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {
    if ( is_single() || is_page() ) {
        return '</div>';
    }
}


add_shortcode('faqstart', 'faq_start_shortcode');
add_shortcode('question', 'faq_question_shortcode');
add_shortcode('answer', 'faq_answer_shortcode');
add_shortcode('faqend', 'faq_end_shortcode');
```

(p.s. you can use [`is_singular()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_singular) as a shorthand for `( is_single() || is_page() )`.